# Powershell Refresh Form

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to adjust a Powershell script i've found, and i'm trying to add a function to it.
In the form is a Password generator included, which just works fine.

But, I would like to add a Reload button in there, so I can change the generated password to another generated password, in case the password contains numbers and letters in a row, which can make the password hard to read.

I've managed to put in the button, but for some reason I can't get the reload button working. Even better would be to make the password generator like a kind of a function, that can be called with a click on the button, and then the Password field gets populated again.

The same function actually should be called at the end of the form, as soon as "Submit" is clicked.
Now the form gets completely cleared after pressing Submit, and I have to reopen the Script to get the password path working again.

Hopefully Someone can help me with this :-)

It would be nice if I can get the password generator function to be recalled with the click of a button, and at the end of the script after pressing Submit.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')

#Password generator
    $chars = "123456789abcdefghijkmnop123456789qrstuvwxyz!-*#@ABCEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray()
    $newPassword=""
    #change the number to length of password you want
    1..10 | ForEach {  $newPassword += $chars | Get-Random };


#the form - change the title, checkboxes textboxes etc...
[xml]$XAML = @"

<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="Company User Creation" MaxHeight="600" Width="480" ResizeMode="NoResize">

    <Grid>
        <Label Name="fnlabel" Content="First Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Name="lnlabel" Content="Last Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="179,24,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="fntxt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,50,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox Name="lntxt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="183,50,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Label Name="samlabel" Content="Logon Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="samtxt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,96,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Label Name="tllabel" Content="Job Title" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,114,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="tltxt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,140,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Label Name="mblabel" Content="Manager" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,160,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="mbtxt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,187,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Label Name="deplabel" Content="Department" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="179,160,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="deptxt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="183,187,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Button Name="Submit" Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="236,464,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Name="Close" Content="Close" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="189,464,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Name="pwd" Content="Refresh" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="315,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="pwtxt" Text="$newPassword" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="183,96,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Label Name="pwlabel" Content="Password" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="179,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Name="dplabel" Content="Display Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="179,114,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="dptxt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="183,140,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Label Name="emlabel" Content="Email Address" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,207,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Name="saplabel" Content="SAP Username" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="256,207,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="emtxt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,233,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
        <TextBox Name="saptxt" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="260,233,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Label Content="Drive Access" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,255,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <CheckBox Name="grpbxgen" Content="APS" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,280,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <CheckBox Name="grpbxprod" Content="Production" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,300,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <CheckBox Name="grpbxhs" Content="Externals" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="307,300,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <CheckBox Name="grpbxfac" Content="Finance" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="164,320,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <CheckBox Name="grpbxsm" Content="General Management" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="307,280,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <CheckBox Name="grpbxqc" Content="HR" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,320,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <CheckBox Name="grpbxqa" Content="Quality Assurance" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="164,300,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <CheckBox Name="grpbxrd" Content="Quality Control" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="164,280,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <CheckBox Name="grpbxmn" Content="Maintenance" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="307,320,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <CheckBox Name="grpbxman" Content="Managers" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,340,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <CheckBox Name="grpbxeng" Content="Engineering" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="164,340,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <CheckBox Name="grpbxpur" Content="Purchasing" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="307,340,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <CheckBox Name="grpbxot" Content="OT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="27,360,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <CheckBox Name="grpbxtrn" Content="Trainers" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="164,360,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@
#Read XAML
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
try{$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )}
catch{Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader"; exit}


# Store Form Objects In PowerShell and Import AD
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object {Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)}
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#close button
$Close.Add_Click({$Form.Close()})

#Refresh Button 
$pwd.Add_Click({
    $pwtxt.Items.Clear()
})

#Create new user from submitted info
$Submit.Add_Click({
 New-ADUser `
-Name $dptxt.Text`
-EmailAddress $emtxt.text `
-DisplayName $dptxt.Text`
-SamAccountName $samtxt.text `
-UserPrincipalName $emtxt.text `
-GivenName $fntxt.text `
-Surname $lntxt.Text `
-Title $tltxt.text `
-Manager $mbtxt.text `
-Department $deptxt.text`
Set-ADUser
-Identity $samtxt.text -add @{extensionAttribute5 = "$saptxt.text"} 
-path 'OU=Users,OU=Company,DC=local';

# 

#specify AD groups and match to form checkboxes 
if ($grpbxgen.isChecked){
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "ADGroup 1" -Members $samtxt.text
}

if ($grpbxprod.isChecked){
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "ADGroup 1" -Members $samtxt.text
}

if ($grpbxhs.isChecked){
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "ADGroup 1" -Members $samtxt.text
}

if ($grpbxfac.isChecked){
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "ADGroup 2" -Members $samtxt.text
}

if ($grpbxsm.isChecked){
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "ADGroup 2" -Members $samtxt.text
}

if ($grpbxqc.isChecked){
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "ADGroup 3" -Members $samtxt.text
}

if ($grpbxqa.isChecked){
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "ADGroup 4" -Members $samtxt.text
}

if ($grpbxmn.isChecked) {
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "ADGroup 9" -Members $samtxt.text
}

if ($grpbxman.isChecked) {
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "ADGroup 10" -Members $samtxt.text
} 

if ($grpbxpur.isChecked) {
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "ADGroup 11" -Members $samtxt.text
} 

if ($grpbxrd.isChecked){
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "ADGroup 5" -Members $samtxt.text
}

if ($grpbxvpn.isChecked){
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "ADGroup 6" -Members $samtxt.text
}

if ($grpbxla.isChecked){
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "ADGroup 7" -Members $samtxt.text
}

if ($grpbx365.isChecked){
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "ADGroup 8" -Members $samtxt.text
}

Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $samtxt.text -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "$newPassword" -Force);

Enable-ADAccount -Identity $samtxt.text`

[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($dptxt.text + " has been created" + " and the password is " + $newPassword)

#clear Form
$fntxt.text =  ''
$lntxt.Text = ''
$emtxt.text = '' 
$mbtxt.text = ''
$samtxt.text = ''
$tltxt.text  = ''
$pwtxt.text = ''
$dptxt.Text = ''
$grpbxgen.isChecked = $false
$grpbxprod.isChecked = $false
$grpbxhs.isChecked = $false
$grpbxfac.isChecked = $false
$grpbxsm.isChecked = $false
$grpbxqc.isChecked = $false
$grpbxqa.isChecked = $false
$grpbxrd.isChecked = $false
$grpbxvpn.isChecked = $false
$grpbxla.isChecked = $false
$grpbx365.isChecked = $false
})




#Show Form
$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the code to generate new a password into a function:

```
function Generate-Password {
    param($Length = 10)
    
    $chars = "123456789abcdefghijkmnop123456789qrstuvwxyz!-*#@ABCEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray()
    $newPassword=""
    #change the number to length of password you want
    1..$Length | ForEach {  $newPassword += $chars | Get-Random }
    
    return $newPassword
}
$newPassword = Generate-Password
```

And then call the function and update the password in the form from the click event handler for the refresh button:

```
$pwd.Add_Click({
    $pwtxt.Text = Generate-Password
})
```

Then inside the submit button click handler, make sure you read the password value directly from the password text box:

```
$Submit.Add_Click({
  # ...
  Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $samtxt.text -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $pwtxt.Text -Force);
  # ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update !!

Unfortunatly it is not working completely as expexted. 
Whenever I click the Refresh button, a new password is created, as should be. 

But as soon I click on Submit, the dialog window that pops up, shows the first generated password. 

So, I'm affraid the password will not be updated in the Active Directory then also.

Comment: @Chris That's because you never read the value of the password text box, you grab the value from the variable you used at the top of the script instead. See updated answer